# Adding 25% Additional Time in PhP

Tags: php

I'm looking for a php calculation that will allow a user to add 25% extra time to two dates/times.

i.e.

> Date: 09/11/2015 
>  Start Time: 10:00 
>  End Time: 11:00 
>   + 25%
>
> = 0 Hours 15 Minutes

Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: Calculate the difference in seconds between the two dates, and multiply that by 1.25

Answer (score 0):

I got around it by using the following:

any amendments welcomed :)

```
  $startTime = '10:00';
  $endTime = '11:00';
  $extraTime = '0.25';
  $diff = (strtotime($endTime) - strtotime($startTime));
  $total = $diff/60 * $extraTime;
  echo sprintf("%2d Hour(s), %02d Minutes", floor($total/60), $total%60);
```